# left join with special condition on right table

Tags: sql, database, join, sqlite, left-join

don't know if this is possible.. I'm using sqlite3
schema:

CREATE TABLE docs (id integer primary key, name string);
CREATE TABLE revs (id integer primary key, doc_id integer, number integer);

I want to select every job joined with only one of its revisions, the one with the highest number. How can I achieve this?
Right now I'm doing a left join and getting everything and then I'm filtering it in the application, but this sucks..

(by the way, can you suggest me a good and easy introductory book on databases and **how they work** and maybe something about sql too..)
thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if your engine supports this, but typically, you would do something like this in ANSI SQL:

```
SELECT docs.*
    ,revs.*
FROM docs
INNER /* LEFT works here also if you don't have revs */ JOIN revs
    ON docs.id = revs.doc_id
    AND revs.number IN (
        SELECT MAX(number)
        FROM revs
        WHERE doc_id = docs.id
    )
```

There are a number of ways to write equivalent queries, using common table expressions, correlated aggregate subqueries, etc.

Comment: Good! Am I correct in thinking that this query is pretty work intensive? It's actually doing a select for every doc.. I will have lots of docs, but only a few revs for each one.. it doesn't make any sense to index the number field does it?

Comment: On the face of it, this would appear to do a subselect on each row, but in my experience, the SQL Server optimizer makes this as equivalent to those with CTEs or correlated subqueries.  I just put this down as the most readable for you.  Like I said, there's lots of ways to skin this cat (I think it shows up 5 times daily here, and I give different answers depending on my feeling).  Your mileage may vary with your engine.

Comment: OrbMan's solution - apparently pre-aggregating and joining - is typically what most engines actually do (I actually usually use that form).  You would have to look at the execution plan to see how your engine handles it.

Answer (score 4):

try this

```
   Select * From docs d
      Join revs r
         On r.doc_id = d.id
   Where r.number = 
         (Select Max(number ) from revs
          Where Doc_Id = d.Id)
```

or, if you want the docs with no Revs (Is this possible?)

```
   Select * From docs d
      Left Join revs r
         On r.doc_id = d.id
           And r.number = 
                (Select Max(number ) from revs
                 Where Doc_Id = d.Id)
```

Comment: almost.. but you're selecting the rev with highest id, I want the one with highest "number". If I add id,max(number) then I get: "SQL error: only a single result allowed for a SELECT that is part of an expression"

Comment: change it to r.numbers = (select max(number)...  The only reason I didn't use the = and used IN is that some SQL dialects are quirky about a subquery which returns a scalar instead of a set, whereas the IN syntax is almost universally supported.

Comment: @luca:   sorry, my bad, I missed that, edited to change it to do the max(number)

Answer (score 2):

```
select d.*, r.max_number
from docs d
left outer join (
    select doc_id, max(number) as max_number
    from revs
    group by doc_id
) r on d.id = r.doc_id
```

Answer (score 1):

Database Design : [Database Design for Mere Mortals](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_ss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=database+design+for+mere+mortals&x=24&y=15) by Hernandez

SQL : [The Practical SQL Handbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201703092)

If you want to hurt your head, any of the SQL books by [Joe Celko](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_ss?url=search-alias%3Dstripbooks&field-keywords=joe+celko&sprefix=joe+celko).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very good list of books for Database Design

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=database+book

Answer (score 0):

If every job has revisions (e.g., starting with rev 0), I would use the same approach as OrbMan, but with an inner join. (If you are certain you are looking for a 1-to-1 match. why not let SQL know, too?)

```
select d.*, r.max_number
from docs d
inner join
(
    select doc_id, max(number) as max_number
    from revs
    group by doc_id
) r on d.id = r.doc_id
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend "A Sane Approach to Database Design" as an excellent introduction to good design practices. (I am slightly biased. I wrote it. But hey, so far it has a 5-star average review on Amazon, none of which reviews were contributed by me or any friends or relatives.)